# Why do I get this syntax error using UPDATE?

Tags: python, mysql

I have the following function:

```
 def Guardar_Modificaciones(self):
    self.usuario.modificar_usuario(self.ID, self.txtNombre.get(), self.txtHA.get(),self.txtIdentificacion.get(),self.txtEdad.get(),self.txtFNacimiento.get(),self.txtEscolaridad.get(),self.txtSS.get(),self.txtEtnia.get(),self.txtContacto.get(),self.txtDireccion.get())
    messagebox.showinfo("Insertar", 'Elemento insertado correctamente')
```

when I use this function to modify the database values:

```
ef modificar_usuario(self, ID, Nombre, HA, Identificacion, Edad, FNacimiento, Escolaridad, SS, Etnia, Contacto, Direccion):
    cur = self.cnn.cursor()
    sql='''UPDATE usuarios SET Nombre='{}', HA='{}', Identificacion='{}', Edad='{}', FNacimiento='{}', Escolaridad='{}', SS='{}', Etnia='{}', Contacto='{}',
    Direccion='{}' WHERE ID = {} '''.format(ID, Nombre, HA, Identificacion, Edad, FNacimiento, Escolaridad, SS, Etnia, Contacto, Direccion)
    cur.execute(sql)
    n=cur.rowcount
    self.cnn.commit()
    cur.close()
    return n
```

it shows me the following error:

raise get_mysql_exception(
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'CARRERA' in 'where clause'

and it is assumed that CARRERA is a data from the Direccion column, not the ID...

Comment: i dit it, and did not work... same error...

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/902417/476 for how to properly interpolate variables into a query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i dont know if this the problem but you miss one " ' " in syntax

```
''"UPDATE usuarios SET Nombre='{}', HA='{}', Identificacion='{}', Edad='{}', FNacimiento='{}', Escolaridad='{}', SS='{}', Etnia='{}', Contacto='{}', Direccion='{}', WHERE ID = '{}' "''
```

and what the type your id?
if int i dont think you have to use '{}' just {} because if you print that its gonna be where ID = '1' not where ID = 1

(edit)
i think the problem in your format, you set the ID in Nombre, move the ID to end

```
sql="UPDATE usuarios SET Nombre='{}', HA='{}', Identificacion='{}', Edad='{}', FNacimiento='{}', Escolaridad='{}', SS='{}', Etnia='{}', Contacto='{}', Direccion='{}', WHERE ID = {}".format(Nombre, HA, Identificacion, Edad, FNacimiento, Escolaridad, SS, Etnia, Contacto, Direccion,ID)
```

Comment: i did removed the ' ', but it did not work. I put three single quotes and one double at the beginning and at the end, like the example you give me, and the error changes, now It move the values ​​one box to the right, and put the data of the viable name in ID and so on , since ID is supposed to be autoincrement...

Comment: ''' "UPDATE usuarios 
        SET Nombre='{}', HA='{}', Identificacion='{}', Edad='{}', FNacimiento='{}', Escolaridad='{}', SS='{}', Etnia='{}', Contacto='{}', Direccion='{}'
        WHERE ID = {}" '''

Comment: version for the right syntax to use near '"UPDATE usuarios 
        SET Nombre='1', HA='OSCAR', Identificacion='2145', Eda' at line 1
and it should be:
    SET Nombre='OSCAR', HA='2145'... and so on...

Comment: maybe you wrong when sent the id @AdriánGuerao

Comment: @AdriánGuerao check my edit, i think thats the problem

Comment: part of the sql code:

CREATE TABLE `usuarios` (
 `ID` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `Nombre` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci',
 `HA` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci',

Comment: if i remove ID from format, it tells me that there are not enough positional arguments...

Comment: I solved it thanks to you, thaks for the help!!